# Changing format of date in calender

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, primeng

I am working on angular app. I am using calender in it. I am using prime ng calender. My code is as follows

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo-whgla5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

HTML:

```
<h5>Popup</h5>
<div class="p-fluid p-grid p-formgrid">
  <div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-4">
    <label for="basic">Basic</label>
    <p-calendar inputId="basic" [(ngModel)]="date1"></p-calendar>
  </div>
</div>
```

code is working fine but I want date in this format [image: format].

How can I do that?

Comment: what format is that? mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy?

Comment: _"but I want date in this format"_ - would simply _typing_ this not have been easier, than uploading an image ...? Also, [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `dateFormat` attribute like this...

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="dateValue" dateFormat="yy/mm/dd"></p-calendar>
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: I want underline below date as shown in image. How I can do that?